# What URI protocols exist on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, uri-scheme

I have scoured the web for a complete list of URI protocols (XXX://) to open different apps in Windows Phone 8. I have found some lists but only with a very small amount of protocols. I am with this wiki-post hoping to make a complete list of protocols and at least cover all the stock apps in Windows Phone 8.

There are many partial lists for example:
http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/URI_Association_Schemes_List http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937(v=vs.105).aspx

However I think it would be great if we could compile a big list of all URL schemes. Even undocumented URL schemes would be interesting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I add all that I found below. Please add if you know any more:

**STOCK APPS**

```
http:[URL]                          Launches the web browser and navigates to the specified URL.
mailto:[email address]              Launches the email app and creates a new message with the specified email address on the To line. Note that the email is not sent until the user taps send.
ms-settings-airplanemode:           Launches the Airplane Mode Settings app.
ms-settings-bluetooth:              Launches the Bluetooth Settings app.
ms-settings-cellular:               Launches the Cellular Settings app.
ms-settings-emailandaccounts:       Launches the email and accounts settings app.
ms-settings-location:               Launches the Location Settings app.
ms-settings-lock:                   Launches the Lock Screen settings app.
ms-settings-wifi:                   Launches the Wi-Fi Settings app.
zune:navigate?appid=[app ID]        Launches the Windows Phone Store and shows the details page for the specified app.
zune:reviewapp                      Launches the Store and shows the review page for the calling app.
zune:reviewapp?appid=app[app ID]    Launches the Store and shows the review page for the specified app. Note that you must prepend “app” to the ID for the specified app. For example, the URI for reviewing an app with the ID fdf05477-814e-41d4-86cd-25d5a50ab2d8 would be zune:reviewapp?appid=appfdf05477-814e-41d4-86cd-25d5a50ab2d8
zune:search?publisher=[publisher name]  Launches the Store and searches for items by publisher name.
zune:search?keyword=[search keyword]&contenttype=app    Launches the Store and searches for apps by keyword.
zune:search?keyword=[search keyword]&publisher=[publisher name]&contenttype=app Launches the Store and searches for the specified content. All parameters are optional. Specifying “contenttype=app” will limit the search to apps. Omitting this parameter will search all content.
ms-drive-to:                        Get driving directions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj710324(v=vs.105).aspx
ms-walk-to:                         Get walking directions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj710324(v=vs.105).aspx
```

**NOKIA APPS**

```
nokia-music:                        Nokia Music app. See http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Nokia_Music_app-to-app_protocol_for_Windows_Phone_8
directions:                         Here Maps. See http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!maps-and-navigation/here-launchers.html
explore-maps:                       Here Maps. See http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!maps-and-navigation/here-launchers.html
guidance-drive:                     Here Maps. See http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!maps-and-navigation/here-launchers.html
guidance-walk:                      Here Maps. See http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!maps-and-navigation/here-launchers.html
places:                             Here Maps. See http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!maps-and-navigation/here-launchers.html
public-transit:                     Here Maps. See http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!maps-and-navigation/here-launchers.html
```

**STORE APPS**

```
metrotube:                          Metrotube, see http://lazywormapps.com/metrotube-uri-schema.html
instagraph:                         Instagraph, see: http://www.geekchamp.com/forums/app-uri-protocol-directory/instagraph-custom-uri-schema
wpcentral:                          Windows Phone Central, see http://jaybennett.co.uk/2013/06/11/using-the-wpcentral-app-uri-schema/
pouch:                              Pouch, see http://jgstechthoughts.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/custom-uri-associations-for-pouch-for-windows-phone/
metrotour:                          Metrotour, see: http://www.geekchamp.com/forums/app-uri-protocol-directory/metrotour-uri-protocol
spotify:                            Spotify, see: https://www.spotify.com/fi/blog/archives/2008/01/14/linking-to-spotify/
mehdoh:                             Mehdoh, see: http://www.mehdoh.com/uri.htm
pictureslab:                        Pictures lab, see: http://kodierer.blogspot.de/2013/07/just-call-us-well-might-call-you-how-to.html
gmaps:                              gMaps, see: http://dreamteam-mobile.com/blog/2013/01/adding-mapping-features-to-your-windows-8-windows-phone-app/
geosense:                           Geo, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI
keyring:                            Keyring, see: http://directblog.schmidtbonn.de/2013/07/11/keyring-uri-schema/
foursquare:                         Foursquare, see: https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client#iphone
fb:
```

References:

http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/URI_Association_Schemes_List

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Nokia keeps a list of URI association schemes on it's developer wiki. That's probably the best place to track available uri schemes. The list is available [here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/URI_Association_Schemes_List)

Comment: Yes, I know, that list is a good start. Think I have included all protocols from that list above however even that list is very incomplete and I have found many more protocols on other sites. Would be great to get a complete list.

Comment: Nokia's list is incomplete indeed, but since it's a wiki we should be able to edit the Nokia page and add missing Uri-schemes. Might make more sense to update the wiki page since it has more visibility than a single questions here at SO.

Comment: Tom, now that Microsoft have taken over develop.nokia.com your link is broken and there appears to be no replacement with the possibility of adding missing uri schemes.

Comment: Edit: It seems to be a case problem. The correct link is http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/URI_Association_Schemes_List