# How do I launch other app from my own app in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, launcher, windows-phone-8.1

I know this is possible because some app like [Transparency Tiles](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/transparency-tiles/f4125e62-a88b-4f7d-b8f6-3cd60069f105) is doing it.

I know we can use [Launchers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769550%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for common tasks or built-in apps in Windows Phone. But how about third party apps like demonstrated by Transparency Tiles?

I have also read that you can launch some apps by URI as long as the app (internal or 3rd party) has registered the [URI "scheme"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) with the phone. Is there a list online where we can find the third party URI scheme?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What URI protocols exist on Windows Phone 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616402/what-uri-protocols-exist-on-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I think I've found some clues

[Nokia URI Association Schemes List](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/URI_Association_Schemes_List)

[URI Schemes for Windows Phone 8 Apps](http://forums.wpcentral.com/software-development-hacking/254971-uri-schemes-windows-phone-8-apps-;.html)

[What URI protocols exist on Windows Phone 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616402/what-uri-protocols-exist-on-windows-phone-8/18616403#18616403)

Comment: Is there a protocol for the Facebook and Twitter official apps? I haven't found ANYTHING.

Comment: try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730280/windows-phone-8-1-how-to-launch-an-installed-app-from-my-app/34487753#34487753