# Windows Phone 8.1 : how to Launch an Installed app From My app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have tried the following links

[How do I launch other app from my own app in Windows Phone 8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235695/how-do-i-launch-other-app-from-my-own-app-in-windows-phone-8-1)

[Call an external app on windows phone 8.1 runtime(not silverlight) xaml c# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037300/call-an-external-app-on-windows-phone-8-1-runtimenot-silverlight-xaml-c-sharp)

but nothing is working for me as i simply wants to launch one app for e.g. angry birds from my app using a button click.

Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app has [a registered URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779670.aspx), then you should be able to use [Launcher.LaunchUriAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701484.aspx) for this. You can also find some help, [here at MSDN - How to launch the default app for a URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779672.aspx).

Otherwise I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed this(twin jellies) app in my phone http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/twin-jellies/391f8a75-d469-4d0a-957c-11ba66675238 
so now how to launch directly from my app without opening windows store..

Comment: @Shanky Check if developer has registered URI for the application.

Comment: the URI of twin jellies is this (391f8a75-d469-4d0a-957c-11ba66675238)  how to check if the developer has registered ?

Comment: @Shanky That's not the URI. You can take a look how registered URIs look likte [for example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18616403/2681948). Most of the apps doesn't have registered URI and I doubt that dev has registered for this app. You may always contact with the developer and ask him.

Comment: :Thanksss for your kind help :)  :-)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

1. setup your app which launch from other.

   add this in WMAppManifest.xaml  between < /token> and < ScreenResolutions>

   ```
   <Extensions>
      <Protocol Name="alsdkcs" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
   </Extensions>
   ```

   add a class "AssociationUriMapper " and override the function "MapUri()"

   ```
   class AssociationUriMapper : UriMapperBase{
      private string tempUri;

      public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri){
         tempUri = System.Net.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.ToString());
         if (tempUri.Contains("alsdkcs:MainPage?id=")){
            int idIndex = tempUri.IndexOf("id=") + 3; //3 is the length of "id="           
            string id = tempUri.Substring(idIndex);

            return new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?id=" + id, UriKind.Relative);
        }
        return uri;
     }
   }
   ```

   and call them from other app.xaml.cs at this section of InitializePhoneApplication() function

   ```
   RootFrame.UriMapper = new AssociationUriMapper(); // add this line only between RootFrame.Navigated += CompleteInitializePhoneApplication; and RootFrame.NavigationFailed += RootFrame_NavigationFailed;
   ```
2. finally call fron other app to launch an app

   ```
   var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri("alsdkcs:MainPage?id="+5)); 
   if (success){
      // URI launched
   }
   else{
     // URI launch failed
   }
   ```

   where "alsdkcs" is protocol name.

more details see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_URIassociations)