# Launching Music app from code

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I want to know if there's any way to navigate user to default music app of Windows Phone?

I mean, in Windows Phone 8 it should launch music+videos hub, and in Windows Phone 8.1 it should launch Xbox Music app.

(I prefer to navigate to Now Playing page directly. But even a way to just navigate to that app is better than nothing.)

*Please even if you know a method that works with just one of OS versions (8, 8.1) share it with me.*

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to launch it with the code:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("xboxmusic:"));
```

If you want to launch *Nokia Music* then:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("nokia-music:"));
```

Some references: [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18616403/2681948) and [this nice blog post from Matt Lacey](http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2014/03/325-windows-phone-apps-you-can-launch.html).

Comment: Is there any other way on how to lauch default FM Radio app (in built app)? I couldn't find any resource.

Comment: @BalasubramaniM I also don't know how to run the FM Radio app.