# How to launch photos app from my app in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to launch the default photos app from my app just like a launcher. One work around way is to iterate over the media library picture collection which is not so good because my app is not so much concerned with it. Is there any launcher for this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Select a picture from the library or show it?

Comment: i want to launch the gallery. I do not want to browse the pictures or select any. i want the user to go there from my app with a click.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's no such way to launch the default photo application as of now, where as you could only access the native photo application of the device in order to access the photos or to select them programmatically for your own use such as to use them for apps like editing etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't launch Photos app from your app. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616402/what-uri-protocols-exist-on-windows-phone-8) is the only available list of apps that can be accessed via url. Also, see [this](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/URI_Association_Schemes_List) for entire list.