# What is the Uri Scheme to open LinkedIn and Twitter App from an Windows Phone 8.1 App?

Tags: c#, twitter, windows-phone-8.1, linkedin-api, uri-scheme

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app. **I need to open a person's profile in the LinkedIn and Twitter App (which is already installed in the phone) from my own app.**

To achieve this functionality I know I need the **URI Scheme** of the above two apps.

I am successful in opening the Facebook app, by using the following code snippet:

```
public async void OpenFbProfile(string id)
{
    Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb:profile_id=" + id)); //worked fine
}
```

Similarly I was trying the same, to open the LinkedIn and Twitter apps, but was unsuccessful.

```
public async void OpenLinkedInProfile(string id)
{
    Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("LinkedIn:profile_id=" + id)); //not working
}

public async void OpenTwitterProfile(string id)
{
    Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("Twitter:profile_id=" + id)); //not working
}
```

So, can anyone tell me the URI Schemes of these two apps?

And what will be the URI to open a person's profile with the profile id, in these two apps?

Comment: have you checked with any of the `C# Twitter API || LinkedIn API` do a google search to see if one exist.. and I am sure there are examples if one does exist

Comment: Will I be able to open the apps with these APIs?

Comment: I did a quick research and understood that these APIs help to get related data, but they don't help to open a profile in the app.

Comment: perhaps there are reasons for that.. have you tried doing it on your own profile ?

Comment: The app itself is not opening, first of all the linkedin/twitter app has to open, then only I will be able to test my profile, right? So I need to know the uri scheme to open the app.

Comment: This really should be dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616402/what-uri-protocols-exist-on-windows-phone-8 so you can update that question if you find scheme for particular apps... I don't know if you can actually list all registered schemes (which probably would be some other duplicate)...

Comment: Ya sure, if I can find the schemes I will update that question!

Answer (score 0):

```
 await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("Twitter:profile?username=@YOUR_TWITTER_USERNAME"));
```

Answer (score 0):

While understandably one maybe looking for a quick answer. Its strongly suggested that one studies the standards behind the technology one is working with.

https://www.chromium.org/developers/web-intents-in-chrome

https://www.w3.org/TR/web-intents/

Both of those shows an abstraction layer method to calling any intent one desires.

One is even able to register their own intents via http://www.openintents.org/intentsregistry/