# Opening twitter profile from within the WP8.1 app

Tags: c#, twitter, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT (universal) app and on About Page I would like to put link to my twitter account, so that people could click it and be transfer to my account in twitter app (if it's installed, I assume otherwise they would have option to install it). Is it at all possible? I think my secondary option is just link to the profile which will open in IE and I don't think it's the best solution. From what I know I think that I need to use some kind of URI-link [What URI protocols exist on Windows Phone 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616402/what-uri-protocols-exist-on-windows-phone-8) but I can't find any info about using it with twitter app.

Comment: Unaware of any URI schema for the twitter app, I'm always using the mobile twitter url to go to the website

Answer (score 0):

Unless Twitter has published documentation on launching their app with a specific scheme, your app will be fragile. Further, the user may not have the official Twitter app installed and either use something else or not have a Twitter account.

You should launch a browser window that directly opens the account. However, unless the user is signed in, it still may not be the experience you want for your users. Given Twitter doesn't prioritize Windows app development, I doubt their web page provides a quick way to launch the app.

This isn't unique to Windows Phone apps either. The same challenge exists in other operating systems.