# Launch app from the Band without Cortana

Tags: microsoft-band

I know it is possible to launch a Windows Phone app when using Cortana on the Microsoft Band. Is it possible to do the same without Cortana (because it is not supported on the user's region)? For example running the app once on the phone, it creates a tile on the Band, and when that tile is tapped, the phone starts the app?

Thanks.

György

Answer (score 1):

Cortana can't launch an app on the phone, it hangs.  Are you seeing it working for you?

There is no way to launch an app from a tile, MSFT has locked that down and even if you were lucky to get a background app to "listen" for events, it can only fire at 15min intervals at best.

Answer (score 0):

Cortana can certainly open an arbitrary app on the phone, I use that functionality myself in an app I have on the store.

Also, it is generally possible to open an app from another app, using the URI scheme ([What URI protocols exist on Windows Phone 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616402/what-uri-protocols-exist-on-windows-phone-8) - that link is for WP8, but I'm quite sure the same mechanism exists in W10).

However, using the URI scheme requires that the first app is active and in the foreground when opening another app, and the question seems to suggest that the first app should only be used initially to create the tile on the band - so that use case is not possible...

Answer (score 0):

This is using Cortana from the MSFT Band 2 to a Windows phone.  It doesn't work for any app.  It just hangs on opening the app.  Cortana on the phone opens the app fine.